# Regex understand \b

Tags: java, regex

I am struggling to understand word boundary \b in regex.
I read that there are three conditions for \b.

- Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a
  word character.
- After the last character in the string, if the last character is a
  word character.
- Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character
  and the other is not a word character.

I am trying to find the start index of the previous match using the java method start()

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class Quetico{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(args[0]);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(args[[1]]);
        System.out.print("match positions: ");
        while(m.find()){
            System.out.print(m.start()+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

% java Quetico "\b" "^23 *$76 bc"

```
//string: ^23 *$76 bc     pattern:\b
//index : 01234567890
```

produces: 1 3 5 6 7 9

I'm having trouble understanding why is produces this result. Because I'm struggling to see the pattern. Ive tried looking at the inverse, \B which produces 0 2 4 8 however this doesn't make it any clearer for me. If you can help clarify this for me it would be appreciated.

Comment: correct, and amended. I made a typo when posting on this forum. I think it has something to do with my understanding of \w \W. i tried the string @aa@@@aa@aa (mimicking my understanding of the word non word pattern) with the pattern \b which produced: 1 3 6 8 9 11

Comment: If you're struggling to understand `\b`, please note that it's very uncommon to use `\b` by itself the way you have.  I think it's usually used for things like `\bcat\b` which will match "cat" but not "scat" or "cats".  Usages like that should be easier to understand.  Apologies if you already knew that.

Comment: its an exam question for java OCP so they like to throw really uncommon stuff at you.
I have just discovered it has something to do with the '$' character. 
"\b" "@aaa" produces 1 4, which i get.
"\b" "$aaa" produces 0 2, which i don't!

Comment: What happens if you put the second string in single quotes instead of double quotes?  In Linux and other Unix flavors, `$` causes the shell to try to expand a variable, and double quote marks don't protect the `$` (but single quote marks do).  I tried your example but with your string as a string literal in the Java program instead of on the Linux command line, and I got 1 3 6 8 9 11.

Comment: thanks, my last example is also false (should be "\b" "$111"). but its exhibiting the behaviour you have just described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't Java here, it's Linux/Unix.  When you put text between double quote marks on the command line, most of the special shell characters such as `*`, `?`, etc. are no longer special--*except for variable interpolation*.  (And some other things, like `!` depending on which shell flavor you're using.)  Thus, if you say

```
% command "this $variable is interesting"
```

if you've set `variable` to `value`, your command will be called with one argument, `this value is interesting`.  In your case, Linux will treat `$7` as a shell script parameter, even though you're not in a shell script; since this isn't set to anything, it's replaced with an empty string, and the result is the same as if you had run

```
% java Quetico "\b" "^23 *6 bc"
```

which gives me `1 3 5 6 7 9` if I use that string literal in a Java program (instead of on the command line).

To prevent `$` from being interpreted by the shell, you need to use single quote marks:

```
% java Quetico "\b" '^23 *$76 bc'
```

Comment: Well I guess this does. Good job.